# Accidently removed postgres default superuser privileges - can I get it back using pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql

From inside Webmin I accidently unmarked the checkbox "Can create databases?" and "Can create users?"

Stupid, I know.

But since it takes a user with superuser privileges to edit/create a user, is there a way to fix this using pgAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

If you just set `NOCREATEROLE` and `NOCREATEDB` on the user `postgres`, you can simply undo that.

If you actually removed the superuser privilege, you will have to start in single user mode (you cannot use pgAdmin for that):

- First, stop the database.
- Then, start it in single user mode:

  ```bash
  /path/to/postgres --single -D /path/to/data/directory postgres
  ```
- Then enter

  ```
  ALTER ROLE postgres SUPERUSER
  ```

  No trailing semicolon!
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit (or whatever sends EOF on your system).
- Start PostgreSQL in the normal way again.